# How can I convert a value bound to a property that is not a DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Consider the following (abbreviated) markup in a custom `UserControl` (with `x:Name="self"`):

```
<Ellipse>
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform >
        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=PixelOffset}"/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>

<controls:CallbackControl DataContext="{Binding Path=Value}" Callback="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=PixelOffsetCallback, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

My problem is that `TranslateTransform.X` is not a `DependencyProperty` so its binding cannot use a converter - at least not with a "ConverterParameter".

But that is what I would need here, because the "PixelOffset" is calculated from the `Value` (which is available in the current DataContext) and the width of the control. If it were a `DependencyProperty`, I could use a converter with a parameter (or a multi-binding).

My solution (seen above) was the implementation of a "CallbackControl".

```
public class CallbackControl : FrameworkElement
{
    public CallbackControl()
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.DataContextChanged += Callback_DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void Callback_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Callback?.Invoke(this.DataContext);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CallbackProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Callback), typeof(Action<object>), typeof(CallbackControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Action<object>)));

    public Action<object> Callback
    {
        get { return (Action<object>)GetValue(CallbackProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CallbackProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then I added the following to my control:

```
    public MyUserControl() //ctor
    {
        PixelOffsetCallback = this.PixelOffsetCallbackImpl; //set before calling InitializeComponent

        InitializeComponent();
    
        this.SizeChanged += MyUserControl_SizeChanged;
        
        //other code
    }

    private void MyUserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PixelOffsetCallbackImpl(PropertyProvider?.Value);
    }

    private void PixelOffsetCallbackImpl(object value)
    {
        PixelOffset = this.ActualWidth * (double) value; 
    }

    public Action<object> PixelOffsetCallback { get; }

    private double _pixelOffset
    public double PixelOffset
    {
        get => _pixelOffset;
        private set => SetField(ref _pixelOffset, value); //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    }
```

Now whenever the `Value` changes or the control's size, I can recalculate and update `PixelOffset` which can be bound to `TranslateTransform.X`.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: "*TranslateTransform.X is not a DependencyProperty*" is wrong. If it would not be a dependency property, you could not bind it.

Comment: You don't explain what else is going on here but with proportional movement maybe proportional everything and a viewbox could work.  An attached dependency property with change callback could be another option. As to which is better... kind of depends what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

My premise was indeed wrong as pointed out in the comments. `TranslateTransform.X` is indeed a `DependencyProperty` - it's `Binding.ConverterParameter` that isn't.

Therefore I probably could have used a Multi-Binding approach.